# DB2 subselect with 'in', limitations?

Tags: db2, subquery

Somebody mentioned to me, that when performing a subselect with 'in' in DB2, there may be a limit to how many results can be returned by the subselect.  If so, does anybody know what that limit is?  Or if it might be dependent on the version of the DB, how to find this information?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to find such information is on IBM's website. For instance, here are the [limitations for DB2 on z/OS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.doc.ugref%2Frlimtas.htm)

I didn't see anything about there being a limit to the number of values in an "IN" clause however the "Maximum number of columns that are in a table or view (the value depends on the complexity of the CREATE VIEW statement) or columns returned by a table function." is 750.

Unrelated to your question - the [DB2 SQL Cookbook](http://mysite.verizon.net/Graeme_Birchall/id1.html) is an excellent reference for working with DB2.